# Budget android phone with decent camera?

Tags: android, camera, mobile-phone

Looking for a new phone for my wife (based in UK). Requirements:

Budget £250 max
Android
Not too big for the hand
Good camera

I personally like the moto brand and she
currently has a moto g5, which has a poor camera so shouldn't be too hard to beat. I don't think she'd want a phone too much bigger than it's 5.7 inch by 2.9 inches. More storage would be good too, but I expect most phones would exceed her current 16gb.

I have a moto g9 plus, and wife likes that camera. So something equivalent or better to that pls. The G9 plus don't seem to still be on sale.

Thanks

Comment: What country? In US you can get almost any phone with great camera with £250.

Comment: I am in the United Kingdom